# Generate proxy object based on wsdl file dynamically in code

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, proxy, wsdl

Hi it is possible generate proxy object from wsdl file in code dynamically?

I know that I can use tool wsdl.exe but I would like have a option download wsdl based on URL and in code generate proxy object.

Client is in C#, web service is in Java.

Comment: WSDL.exe is a .NET assembly, have you tried taking it into Reflector or ILSpy to figure out how it does its magic?

Comment: @M.Babcock Maybe .NET Framework have own class for this purpose and diassembly wsdl.exe is not needed.

Comment: Maybe, but if google hasn't told you yet and you can't figure it out then wsdl.exe would be a good place to start...

Comment: wsdl.exe would _not_ be a good place to start. It is based on the legacy ASMX technology and should not be used for new development. WCF and svcutil.exe should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Wsdl.exe uses the framework classes from System.Xml and System.Web.Services to does its magic. However, those classes are obscure and quite difficult to find using a Google search, unless you specifically know the class names themselves.

A good idea is to look at Mono's wsdl.exe source code: http://c-cpp.r3dcode.com/files/mono/2/10.2/mcs/tools/wsdl/MonoWSDL2.cs

This will get you as far as generating the stub code.

Edit: John thinks that asmx is legacy, and svcutil is the way to go. If you ask me, SOAP itself is legacy and REST is the way to go. But since the question is about SOAP and svcutil is supposedly a better technology, here's how svcutil works:

http://c-cpp.r3dcode.com/files/mono/2/10.2/mcs/tools/svcutil/Driver.cs.

Comment: -1: this will generate proxy code based on a legacy technology which should not be used for new development.